# Display child rows in Django admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to display a model's related child rows using the Django admin interface? An example model:

```py
def Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    ....

def Child(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    Parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    ...
```

In the admin interface, when viewing a particular Parent object might display something like:

```
Name: Jack

Children: 

    Bob
    Jenny
    Sam
    ....
```

I understand that I can extend the admin views manually, just wondering if there's a bit of magic that I can add to my admin.py file instead.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could add the child objects as [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin).

```
class ChildInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Child

class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ChildInline,
    ]
```